# Fetch mobile number programmatically

Tags: ios, contacts

I am developing an app in iOS. I can retrieve the first and last name of person but what i want is how can I retrieve the mobile number information. I already have this code to fetch first and last name.

```
CFErrorRef error = NULL;
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &error);

if (addressBook != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Succesful.");


    NSArray *allContacts = (__bridge_transfer NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);


    NSUInteger i = 0; for (i = 0; i < [allContacts count]; i++)
    {

        ABRecordRef contactPerson = (__bridge ABRecordRef)allContacts[i];


        firstName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson,kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
        lastName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonLastNameProperty);


        fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName, lastName];


} else {

    NSLog(@"Error Reading Address Book");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all phone entries using the code below.
I also specified few types of phone types to give you an idea how to deal with that.

```
ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

for (CFIndex i=0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumbers); i++) 
{
    NSString* phoneLabel = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phoneNumbers, i);
    NSString* phoneNumber = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, i);

    if([phoneLabel isEqualToString:(NSString *)kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel])
    {

    }
    else if([phoneLabel isEqualToString:(NSString *)kABPersonPhoneIPhoneLabel])
    {

    }

    CFRelease(phoneNumber);
    CFRelease(phoneLabel);
}

CFRelease(phoneNumbers);
```

Comment: For one, it introduces more unexplained complexity and solves something not even asked for.

Comment: If anyone is deluded enough to call this an 'answer', then it's one of the worst I've ever seen in my life.

Comment: He is asking how to get "mobile number information" so he need to know about all different types of phone entires. Come on give better answer instead of jumping on me :)

Comment: I modify some of your code and it worked. Worked like a charm. Cool.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch phone numbers using below code

```
 ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate(); 

  CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);

  CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);
  for(int i = 0; i < nPeople; i++) 
  { 
      //  Getting the person record ... 
       ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, i); 
       ABMultiValueRef phones = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

       for (CFIndex i=0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(phones); i++) 
       {
            NSString* phoneLabel = (__bridge_transfer  NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phones, i);
            NSString* phoneNumber = (__bridge_transfer  NSString*) ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, i);

       }
       CFRelease(phones);
  }
  CFRelease(allPeople);
  CFRelease(addressBook);
```

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski It is not a copy of you code. Its mine implementation.

Comment: You really forgot to copy a lot of CFReleases which will create a lot of leaks. I cannot image having implementation like that :)

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski you try your code. Let me know if you able to run your code. If not then try mine code…. :)